# How to send files from soap lite client to wcf service?

Tags: wcf, file, soap, service

I have a wcf service set up to accept basic http binding.  I want to send an excel file from perl soap lite to my wcf service.  What is the simpliest way to send this file?  I was looking at mtom/mime, but they seem complicated and I don't know if soap lite uses mtom/mime.  I was also thinking of using base64 string to encode the file first, then send it.  If I use base64 encode, what datatype should I specify as the operation contract parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

byte[] will be automatically base64 encoded and is the most robust and compatible way of sending binary attachments.  I would not use anything esle unless I completely controlled both sides of conversation (and if I did always control both sides I wouldn't use SOAP).

Comment: So if I use byte[], what will the code be on perl side to read the file as binary and encode it to base64?

Comment: it depends on your SOAP client library.  I've never used one in Perl, but Java, C# and Python libraries I've used automatically base64-encode byte arrays.

Answer (score 1):

MK. it turns out you are right.  I used the below code to read in the file "in.xls" as binary into $data, then add it as a value in soap lite and it automatically tranformed into a byte[] on my wcf service.

```
open FHDL, "in.xls" or die $!;
binmode FHDL;
my ($buffer, $data, $n);
while (($n = read FHDL, $buffer, 4) != 0) {
    print "$n bytes read\n";
     $data .= $buffer ;
}
close FHDL;
$logisticOrder->attachment($data);
```

I just had to increase byte array size on my host.

```
<binding name="NetTcpBinding_ImageResizerServiceContract" closeTimeout="00:01:00" 
                openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" 
                transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions" 
                hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10" 
                maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxConnections="10" 
                maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"> 
                                <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" 
                                                          maxStringContentLength="2147483647" 
                                                          maxArrayLength="2147483647" 
                                                          maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" 
                                                          maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" /> 
                                <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" enabled="false" />
                        </binding>
```

Thank you